# Animation causes scroll bar in smaller screens

Tags: html, css, animation, responsive

> This animation is working good on large screens but it is causing scroll bar to appear when it slides in from the right side. The scroll bar disappears after the animation is completed. Is there any way to prevent the scroll bar from appearing?

```
.intros {
  color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  font-family: Raleway;
  animation: heading;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }  

 @keyframes heading {
  0% {right: -700px}
  100% {right: 0} 
 }
```

Comment: try setting `overflow: hidden` to the container or `body` whatever it is.

Comment: It is not working, I found out that it is another javascript animation that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overflow: hidden` in either the body or the class `.intro` might be the solution, this is because the `overflow` CSS property tells the element what to do when the content becomes too big. Depending on where the scrollbar is showing you can use `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`. The x and y represent the y-axis(vertical) and x-axis(horizontal).

Also if you doing animations, you should use `translate`, in your case `translate:-700px`